# Do average on hashes

Tags: ruby

lets say i got 3 hashes:

```
hash1={
a => 1,
b => 2,
c => 4
}


hash2={
b => 1,
c => 3
}

hash3={
a => 2,
b => 1,
c => 3,
d => 4
}
```

I want to average stuff to a new hash according to keys, so new hash will be

```
result={a=>1.5,b=>4/3,c=>10/3,d=>4}
```

meaning if key not exists in one hash we don't count it as 0.

is there an elegant way?

Comment: How is it decided when you want a `Rational` or a `Float`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = {}
[hash1, hash2, hash3].each{|h| h.each{|k, v| (result[k] ||= []).push(v)}}
result.each{|k, v| result[k] = v.inject(:+).to_f/v.length}
result # =>
# {
#   a => 1.5,
#   b => 1.3333333333333333,
#   c => 3.3333333333333335,
#   d => 4.0
# }
```